# Mobile Breakpoint Using Bourbon/Neat/Refills

Tags: css, sass, bourbon, neat

I have created a rails app using `bourbon/neat/bitters/refills` for the `sass`.

So far, have tried adding a few of the refills: centered nav & hero.

Testing in a desktop browser and resizing window down to smallest breakpoint works perfectly: shifts from large to medium to smallest breakpoint (horizontal nav eventually collapses & one column layout beneath).

However, when actually viewing on iphone, it seems to display the desktop breakpoint layout in safari for all the refills.

Has anybody else run into this problem?

Answer (score -1):

### What worked for me (meta viewport)

After long hours I found this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And it did the trick.

---

### About Sass

Careful with the refills, as Ian Wootten said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26742344/875494), this is not CSS this is SCSS so you have to compile it to produce CSS.
the simplest way is to checkout http://sass-lang.com/install

to install Sass and then use the command to produce HTML (compiling)

```
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

Follow the complete instructions here: [using sass docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass)

Comment: How many times are you going to copy/paste this as an answer?  There's nothing here to debug, how can you even attempt to provide an answer?